# How to get the inner text of dynamically generated buttons in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to get the text of a button generated on a page when a button is clicked. The buttons are generated in a document fragment and then appended to the DOM. 
I've written a function to get the text, but when I click a button, nothing is logged to the console.
Here's what I've written so far:

```js
// get the text of any button clicked
function get_text() 
{
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  buttons.onclick = function () {
    console.log('Button ' + this.innerText + ' clicked');
  }
} // ends get_text function

get_text();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) 
{
  var page_title = document.getElementById('res_number');
  page_title.innerHTML = 'Data';
  var keys = Object.keys(res_cap);
  var length = keys.length;
  var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) 
  {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('value', keys[i]);
    button.innerText = keys[i];
    docFrag.appendChild(button);
  }
  document.getElementById('main').appendChild(docFrag);
}); // ends domcontentloaded event listener

var res_cap = {
  1264    : 500000,
  13151   : 1710189,
  13154   : 5098599,
  20813   : 1009625,
  20814   : 840000,
  200814  : 1056231,
  200815  : 912510,
  22033   : 1069687,
  24140   : 524500,
  25191   : 125905,
  27916   : 998033,
  28150   : 307523,
  31901   : 77112,
  31902   : 77112,
  32939   : 5028131,
  33710   : 557152,
  33930   : 928917,
  43210   : 547733,
  43610   : 561586,
  43626   : 7000,
  51770   : 250000,
  51771   : 1100000,
  51772   : 1021416,
  52698   : 1018576,
  53116   : 782764,
  62310   : 556293,
  62518   : 272600,
  63210   : 590902,
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <div id='main'>
      <h1 id='res_number'></h1>
      <table id='res_table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th id='table_header' colspan='3'>Title</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>C1</th>
            <th>C2</th>
            <th>C3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div> <!-- ends main div -->
    <!-- custom js file -->
    <script src='../js/main.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I get the buttons to log to the console their inner text property on click? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getElementsByTagName()` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) not a single element. You can iterate the `HTMLCollection` and attach event to each element.

```
function get_text() 
{
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function () {
      console.log('Button ' + this.innerText + ' clicked');
    }
  }
} // ends get_text function
```

`get_text()` should be called after the elements are appended to the `document`.

```
..
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(docFrag);
get_text();
..
```

Comment: This worked for me! I had tried some of these things but didn't have all the pieces. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onclick`:

```
function myCustomAlert(parm) {
alert(param);
}
button.onclick = myCustomAlert(keys[i])
```